# Fresco lib in Html.HtmlFrom

Tags: android, fresco

I'm already using Fresco library in my project.
I wonder if we can use it also in the `ImageGetter` from `Html.HtmlFrom`.
Here's my code as an example.

```
public class ItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Html.ImageGetter {

    private TextView contentTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        contentTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.itemContentTextView);

        String content = getIntent().getStringExtra("content");

        contentTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(content, this, null));
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried to use as follows:

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        SimpleDraweeView draweeView = new SimpleDraweeView(getBaseContext());
        draweeView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(source));
        return draweeView.getDrawable();
    }
```

But did not load any Picture.
Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getTopLevelDrawable()`, not `getDrawable()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(source)) {
            return null;
        }
        SimpleDraweeView simpleDraweeView = new SimpleDraweeView(mContext);
        ImageRequestBuilder imageRequestBuilder = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(source));
        DraweeController draweeController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setImageRequest(imageRequestBuilder.build())
                .setOldController(simpleDraweeView.getController())
                .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                .build();
        simpleDraweeView.setController(draweeController);
        Drawable drawable = simpleDraweeView.getDrawable();
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        return drawable;
    }
```